# see NodeJs version and were installed

Tags: node.js

I've installed node js via sudo apt-get (I've often updated some) and node via nave on npm but when I type in console, 
`nodejs -v` will return **v0.10.18** and when type `node -v` will return **v0.8.23**, 

I'd like to know how to see every node js were installed from both side.

Comment: Done. but I suggest you to see the answer before you ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List installed node packages:

```
dpkg --get-selections  | grep node
```

List installed node by `nvm`:

```
nvm ls
```

EDIT: misunderstood OP's question

Comment: no, I used `whereis nodejs` and `whereis node` to do that, but I want to see every node that I was installed on my PC..